# How to access the inner fields in a json file in Jenkins pipeline using Groovy

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
{
  "Product": [{
  "flm": [{
       "101": [{
            "value": "R36.0 flm",
            "revision": ["111","11br"]
        }]
        "101.1": [{
            "value": "R36.0 flm",
            "revision": ["111","11br","11we"]
        }]
        "202": [{
            "value": "R37.0 flm",
            "revision": ["111"]
        }]
        "301": [{
            "value": "R38.0 flm",
            "revision": ["222"]
        }]
  }]
  "cod": [{
       "101": [{
            "value": "R36.0 cod",
            "revision": ["111"]
        }]
        "202": [{
            "value": "R37.0 cod",
            "revision": ["111"]
        }]
        "301": [{
            "value": "R38.0 cod",
            "revision": ["222"]
        }]
  }]
  "lsp": [{
       "101": [{
            "value": "R36.0 lsp",
            "revision": ["111","11br"]
        }]
        "202": [{
            "value": "R37.0 lsp",
            "revision": ["111"]
        }]
        "301": [{
            "value": "R38.0 lsp",
            "revision": ["222"]
        }]
  }]
  "urm": [{
       "101": [{
            "value": "R36.0 urm",
            "revision": ["111","11br"]
        }]
        "202": [{
            "value": "R37.0 urm",
            "revision": ["111"]
        }]
        "301": [{
            "value": "R38.0 urm",
            "revision": ["222"]
        }]
    }]

   }]

  }
```

I want to print/access the value/revision fields in the json file using groovy and compare if it matches my input ("11br" ,R36.0 lsp ) if product is (lsp and 101). I can only reach till 101 and later i am not sure how to extract further values. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`JsonSlurper.parseText(json)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.13/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) for that - it will produce a map of maps that you can traverse and extract interesting values. In your case it is important to mention that you have to deal with lists of objects (usually they contain only one object), so traversing will produce lists of lists etc. In this case Groovy's `.flatten()` method is very helpful. Consider following script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''
{
  "Product": [
    {
      "flm": [
        {
          "101": [
            {
              "value": "R36.0 flm",
              "revision": [
                "111",
                "11br"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "101.1": [
            {
              "value": "R36.0 flm",
              "revision": [
                "111",
                "11br",
                "11we"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "202": [
            {
              "value": "R37.0 flm",
              "revision": [
                "111"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "301": [
            {
              "value": "R38.0 flm",
              "revision": [
                "222"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "cod": [
        {
          "101": [
            {
              "value": "R36.0 cod",
              "revision": [
                "111"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "202": [
            {
              "value": "R37.0 cod",
              "revision": [
                "111"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "301": [
            {
              "value": "R38.0 cod",
              "revision": [
                "222"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "lsp": [
        {
          "101": [
            {
              "value": "R36.0 lsp",
              "revision": [
                "111",
                "11br"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "202": [
            {
              "value": "R37.0 lsp",
              "revision": [
                "111"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "301": [
            {
              "value": "R38.0 lsp",
              "revision": [
                "222"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "urm": [
        {
          "101": [
            {
              "value": "R36.0 urm",
              "revision": [
                "111",
                "11br"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "202": [
            {
              "value": "R37.0 urm",
              "revision": [
                "111"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "301": [
            {
              "value": "R38.0 urm",
              "revision": [
                "222"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
'''

def root = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def lsp101 = root.Product.lsp.'101'.flatten()

def value = lsp101.value.first()
def revisions = lsp101.revision.flatten()

def expectedValue = 'R36.0 lsp'
def expectedRevision = '11br'

assert expectedValue == value && expectedRevision in revisions
```

It extracts `value` and a list of `revisions` for path `$.Product.lsp.101` and compares with expected values. Hope it helps understanding how can you work with JSON in Groovy. For more information and examples don't hesitate to visit Groovy manual page that describes how to work with JSON in details - http://groovy-lang.org/json.html